# How to show nextweek of dates in calender

Tags: android, android-calendar

Below is my code that display current week of dates,now I add two new button in my code 
`btnpreviousweek`,`btnnextweek` I want to show next week and previous week dates on button click how do I do? how I change dates to show next week of dates or previous week of dates?? Also this code show dates from Sunday to Saturday I just want to display only Monday to Friday this is my screen-shot

[image]

```
public class MyCalendarActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String tag = "MyCalendarActivity";

    private TextView currentMonth;
    private ImageView prevMonth;
    private ImageView nextMonth;
    Button btnpreviousweek,btnnextweek;

    private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;
    private Calendar _calendar;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private int month, year;
    private int actualYear, actualMonth, actualDay;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
    private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_calendar_view);

        _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        actualYear = year;
        actualMonth = month;
        actualDay = _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
                + year);

        btnpreviousweek = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnpreviousweek);
        btnnextweek = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnnextweek);

        btnpreviousweek.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //////////////////////////        what i write here         /////////////////////////
            }
        });

        btnnextweek.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //////////////////////////        what i write here         /////////////////////////
            }
        });

        prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
        prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));

        nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
        nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);
        calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param month
     * @param year
     */
    private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == prevMonth) {
            if (month <= 1) {
                month = 12;
                year--;
            } else {
                month--;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);
            setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
        }
        if (v == nextMonth) {
            if (month > 11) {
                month = 1;
                year++;
            } else {
                month++;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);
            setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // Inner Class
    public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
        private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
        private final Context _context;

        private final List<String> list;
        private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
        private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
                "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
        private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
                "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };
        private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
                31, 30, 31 };
        private int daysInMonth;
        private int currentDayOfMonth;
        private int currentWeekDay;
        private Button gridcell;
        private TextView num_events_per_day;
        private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
        private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MMM-yyyy");

        // Days in Current Month
        public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                int month, int year) {
            super();
            this._context = context;
            this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                    + "Year: " + year);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

            Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

            // Print Month
            printMonth(month, year);

            // Find Number of Events
            eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
        }

        private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
            return months[i];
        }

        private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
            return weekdays[i];
        }

        private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
            return daysOfMonth[i];
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        /**
         * Prints Month
         * 
         * @param mm
         * @param yy
         */
        private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
            Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
            int trailingSpaces = 0;
            int daysInPrevMonth = 0;

            int currentMonth = mm - 1;
            String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
            daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

            Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having " +  
                daysInMonth + " days.");

            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 
                    getCurrentDayOfMonth());
            Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

            int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

            Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is " + 
                    getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
            Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
            Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

            if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                if (mm == 2) ++daysInMonth;
                else if (mm == 3)
                    ++daysInPrevMonth;

            // move at the begging of the week
            int i = getCurrentDayOfMonth();
            int j = currentWeekDay;
            while (i > 1 && j > 0) {
                i--;
                j--;
            }
            // print the week, starting at Sunday
            for (j = 0; i <= daysInMonth && j < 7; i++, j++) {
                Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " " + 
                        getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
                // If it is the current date, printing in BLUE (Orange)
                if (i == actualDay && mm == actualMonth && yy == actualYear) {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-" + 
                            getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                } else {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-" + 
                            getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
         * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
         * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
         * day.
         * 
         * @param year
         * @param month
         * @return
         */
        private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
                int month) {
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, 
                        false);
            }

            // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
            gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
            gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

            // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

            Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
            String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
            String theday = day_color[0];
            String themonth = day_color[2];
            String theyear = day_color[3];
            if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null))  {
                if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                    num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                    Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                    num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
                }
            }

            // Set the Day GridCell
            gridcell.setText(theday);
            gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
            Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
                    + theyear);

            if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.lightgray));
            }
            if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.lightgray02));
            }
            if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
                gridcell.setText("(" + theday + ")");

                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orrange));
            }
            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
            //    selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
            Log.e("Selected date", date_month_year);
            try {
                Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
                Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
            return currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
            this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
            this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
        }

        public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
            return currentWeekDay;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you get any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help for you,

```
 Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -k);
    Date daysBeforeDate = cal.getTime();
    String start_dt1 = "" + daysBeforeDate;
```

you can replace the k by the number 7 so that you get the date before seven days, like that you can use k instead of -k for date after k days.

Comment: how i add printMonth() function on button click is show error
The method printMonth(int, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: call the function inside onClick method, like  public void onClick(View arg0) {
            printMonth(int, int);
        }

Comment: i make another funciton name printMonthh2(int int) and copy all printMonthcode  now tel me how do i change days of next week when button click???? how i change code of print month to show nextweek of dates???

Comment: tha start_dt1 gives you the full date , if you month,year,date separately the extract from daysBeforeDate like daysBeforeDate.getMonth ,daysBeforeDate.getYear,etc